# Importação de DLL em C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll

Entrei em um projeto recente que usa uma impressora da Perto para imprimir cupons fiscais.

O ultimo que trabalhou no projeto usava uma DLL (se não me engano em C++) que gerenciava a impressora.

No projeto, essa DLL é importada através do seguinte comando:

```
[DllImport(@"C:\InfoSAT\ptptrpro.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern Int32 SetProtocol(Int32 protocol);
```

Ao tentar executar o método importado, me é arremessado uma `System.DllNotFoundException` informando que não foi possível encontrar o modulo especificado.

Achei curioso esse erro porquê na pasta informada no Import tem essa DLL.

Meu palpite é:

1- Esse projeto foi feito na época usando o Visual C# 2010 Express, e eu estou tentando abri-lo no Visual Studio 2015, pode estar acontecendo alguma incompatibilidade;

2- Essa DLL pode estar corrompida (dificil, mas não impossivel);

3 - Outra coisa que eu não consegui imaginar.

Obrigado a quem puder me ajudar.

Comment: Veja no projeto se ela esta referenciada, para isso vá até References no project explorer do VS... Se ela não estiver, adicione uma referencia para ela... Vai ser até melhor do que "importar na mão", pois ai voce terá os métodos via intellisense.

Também é necessário adicionar a biblioteca atraves do comando 'using' para ter acesso a ela.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, eu tentei fazer isso, mas ao tentar adicionar a dll, é exibido: A referente to 'C:\InfoSAT\ptptrpro.ddl' could not be added. Please make sure that the files is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component.

Comment: Tem que verificar a compatibilidade da plataforma, tenta compilar no visual studio para x86 ou x64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode ser que uma das dependências da dll que você está tentando referenciar não está sendo encontrada.

Um bom programa para verificar dependências de dlls é o [DependencyWalker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) que vai te listar as dependências da dlls e quais que podem estar faltando.

Answer (score 0):

No Visual Studio, no gerenciador de soluções tem o item [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Clique com o botão direito do mouse nele e clique em adicionar referência. Aparecerá uma janela de referências clique no botão procurar e selecione a sua dll.

[image: Depois de selecionar ela aparecerá neste menu, depois a selecone e as namespaces do c# serão carregadas]

Depois de selecionar ela aparecerá neste menu, depois a selecione e as namespaces do c# serão carregadas depois de OK.

Se você estiver fazendo uma dll do c++ e usá-la em projeto c++, [leia esta pergunta que eu respondi.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/178823/erro-de-refer%C3%AAncia-na-dll/509759#509759)

Mas se você usar dll em ambas as duas c++ para c#  e vice-versa, tente encontrar algum tutorial. Espero que isso ajude.