# Erro de referência na DLL

Tags: c++, dll

Estou criando uma DLL que precisa exportar 11 funções do CEN/XFS, porém existe uma função que consome um arquivo de cabeçalho. Acho que o erro está em consumir um método de um cabeçalho que não está declarado no meu escopo, alguém pra ajudar ?

Essa dll irá se comunicar com o XFS Manager.

Meu código é esse (Minha DLL - dllmain.cpp):

```
HRESULT WINAPI WFPOpen ( HSERVICE hService, LPSTR lpszLogicalName, HAPP hApp, LPSTR lpszAppID, DWORD dwTraceLevel, DWORD dwTimeOut, HWND hWnd, REQUESTID ReqID, HPROVIDER hProvider, DWORD dwSPIVersionsRequired, LPWFSVERSION lpSPIVersion, DWORD dwSrvcVersionsRequired, LPWFSVERSION lpSrvcVersion)
{

printf("INTO WFPOpen");
WFSRESULT * lpWFSResult;
HRESULT result;
SYSTEMTIME st; 
HRESULT rt;
GetSystemTime(&st); 

//o erro ocorre aki
result = WFMAllocateBuffer(sizeof(WFSRESULT), WFS_MEM_ZEROINIT, (void**)&lpWFSResult);

if(result!=WFS_SUCCESS){
        return WFS_ERR_INTERNAL_ERROR; 
}                    

return WFS_SUCCESS;
}
```

Header file (XFSADMIN.H):

```
HRESULT extern WINAPI WFMAllocateBuffer(ULONG ulSize, ULONG ulFlags, LPVOID * lppvData);
```

Minha dll.h (11 métodos que serão exportados)

```
class DLLIMPORT DllClass
{
public:
    HRESULT WINAPI WFPCancelAsyncRequest (HSERVICE hService, REQUESTID RequestID);
    HRESULT WINAPI WFPClose (HSERVICE hService, HWND hWnd, REQUESTID ReqID);
    HRESULT WINAPI WFPDeregister (HSERVICE hService, DWORD dwEventClass, HWND hWndReg, HWND hWnd, REQUESTID ReqID);
    HRESULT WINAPI WFPExecute (HSERVICE hService, DWORD dwCommand, LPVOID lpCmdData, DWORD dwTimeOut, HWND hWnd, REQUESTID ReqID);
    HRESULT WINAPI WFPGetInfo (HSERVICE hService, DWORD dwCategory, LPVOID lpQueryDetails, DWORD dwTimeOut, HWND hWnd, REQUESTID ReqID);
    HRESULT WINAPI WFPLock (HSERVICE hService, DWORD dwTimeOut, HWND hWnd, REQUESTID ReqID);
    HRESULT WINAPI WFPOpen (HSERVICE hService, LPSTR lpszLogicalName, HAPP hApp, LPSTR lpszAppID, DWORD dwTraceLevel, DWORD dwTimeOut, HWND hWnd, REQUESTID ReqID, HPROVIDER hProvider, DWORD dwSPIVersionsRequired, LPWFSVERSION lpSPIVersion, DWORD dwSrvcVersionsRequired, LPWFSVERSION lpSrvcVersion);
    HRESULT WINAPI WFPRegister (HSERVICE hService,  DWORD dwEventClass, HWND hWndReg, HWND hWnd, REQUESTID ReqID);
    HRESULT WINAPI WFPSetTraceLevel (HSERVICE hService, DWORD dwTraceLevel);
    HRESULT WINAPI WFPUnloadService ();
    HRESULT WINAPI WFPUnlock (HSERVICE hService, HWND hWnd, REQUESTID ReqID);   
  };
```

Porém ocorre esse erro ao compilar a DLL.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mais precisamente aqui:

```
$(CPP) -shared $(LINKOBJ) -o $(BIN) $(LIBS) -Wl,--output-def,$(DEF),--out-  implib,$(STATIC),--add-stdcall-alias
```

Comment: deve estar faltando uma lib em seu projeto, talvez xfs_supp.lib

Comment: e onde devo colocar ? na raiz do projeto já tentei e não adiantou.

Comment: que está faltando uma lib do XFS é praticamente certo, e essa lib "xfs_supp.lib" exporta a a função que está faltando (WFMAAllocateBuffer)...você deve configurar essa lib como input no passo de link do processo de build da dll...mais do que isso não dá pra dizer, sem conhecer o projeto

Comment: Se eu te passar por email o que estou fazendo, poderia dar uma olhada ? pois preciso exportar essa dll apenas para teste.

Comment: coloque mais informações sobre o projeto aqui mesmo...outras pessoas vão poder olhar

Comment: Coloquei mais informações.

Comment: você está usando mingw ou cygwin (ou algo assim), será que as libs XFS funcionam nesse ambiente ? isso eu não sei...

de qualquer maneira, olhando na linha de link-edição, será que em "$(LIBS)" estão os nomes de todas as libs necessárias ?

Outra coisa, isso aqui "-Wl,--output-def,$(DEF),--out-  implib,$(STATIC),--add-stdcall-alias" está estranho, aquele espaço entre "--out- implib" é assim mesmo ? não deveria ter uma vírgula aí ? estou chutando aqui, mas as sub-opções de uma opção "-Wl" devem ser separadas por vírgula, não por espaço

enfim, só consigo chegar até aqui

Comment: Já tentou `#pragma comment(lib, "xfs_supp.lib")` no seu `dllmain.cpp`?

Answer (score 1):

Para fazer essa referência com a DLL, é necessário de uma lib.
Se ao compilar sua DLL, poderá encontrar alguns arquivos, se você encontrar uma .a ou .lib em seu projeto ele será seu linker com sua DLL.

Exemplo: Quem usa o Dev-C++ ou o Visual Studio pode aparecer algum exemplo de DLL.

```
#ifndef _DLL_H_
#define _DLL_H_

#if BUILDING_DLL
#define DLLIMPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLLIMPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class DLLIMPORT DllClass
{
    public:
        DllClass();
        virtual ~DllClass();
        void HelloWorld();
};

#endif
```

Esse é um exemplo do Dev-C++ da dll.h. Note que a classe recebe a macro com __declspec(dllexport), pois é necessário para exportar a classe e usá-la.

```
/* Replace "dll.h" with the name of your header */
#include "dll.h"
#include <windows.h>

DllClass::DllClass()
{

}

DllClass::~DllClass()
{

}

void DllClass::HelloWorld()
{
    MessageBox(0, "Hello World from DLL!\n","Hi",MB_ICONINFORMATION);
}

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL,DWORD fdwReason,LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
    switch(fdwReason)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        {
            break;
        }
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        {
            break;
        }
        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        {
            break;
        }
        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    
    /* Return TRUE on success, FALSE on failure */
    return TRUE;
}
```

Esse é a dllmain.cpp e recebe uma função da WINAPI, lembre-se que a WINAPI está declarado na windows.h.
Depois de compilar com todos os arquivos incluindo a .h, você recebe certos arquivos:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Temos o arquivos fonte. E também temos o .dll , .def e uma .a
Após disso dependendo de seu IDE, você inclua a lib que é a ".a" ou ".lib" se aparecer, nos parâmetros do linker(se tiver) ou no compilador, no caso do Dev-C++ tem em opções do projeto a parte do C e C++ Compiler e Linker e um botão "Adicionar Biblioteca" e você adiciona isso no Linker.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após a inclusão você pode criar um cabeçalho com as funções da DLL:

```
#ifndef EXEMPLO_H
#define EXEMPLO_H

#define DLLIMPORT __declspec(dllexport)

class DLLIMPORT DllClass
{
    public:
        DllClass();
        virtual ~DllClass();
        void HelloWorld();
};

#endif
```

Se você chamar uma classe ou função sem essa lib da DLL, não vai funcionar.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se tudo ocorrer bem fizer esse passo a passo e aparecer:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Podemos dizer que seu programa tem a necessidade de sua DLL, é um requerimento. Finalmente colocando a DLL ao lado do programa.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Espero que esse tutorial da DLL o ajude-o.

> que está faltando uma lib do XFS é praticamente certo, e essa lib "xfs_supp.lib" >exporta a a função que está faltando (WFMAAllocateBuffer)...você deve configurar >essa lib como input no passo de link do processo de build da dll...mais do que >isso não dá pra dizer, sem conhecer o projeto – zentrunix 23/01/17 às 14:42

Isso é verdade, eu tinha esse caso mas com a urlmon.h e se você usar essa biblioteca do XPS, precisa dessa lib.
[A xfs_supp.lib encontra-se aqui.](https://github.com/sebastianscatularo/freexfs/blob/master/lib/xfs_supp.lib)

Comment: Esse parâmetro no makefile.win "implib,$(STATIC)" ele faz com que o compilador cria a lib para fazer o link com a DLL e "--output-def,$(DEF)" cria um arquivo com as referências das funções como esta que foi dado erro.