# Problema com chamada de função em DLL (C)

Tags: c

Estou com problemas ao executar um código que utiliza uma função de uma DLL, que tem um ponteiro como argumento, conforme o protótipo:

```
DLLIMPORT void add_std_func(object list)
```

Seguem as definições da macro `DLLIMPORT`:

```
#if BUILDING_DLL
#define DLLIMPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLLIMPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

e do tipo `object`:

```
typedef char *string;
/*...*/
typedef void *pointer
/*...*/
typedef struct str_Intern_Object    Intern_Object, *object;
/*...*/
typedef struct str_Class *Class;

struct str_Class{
    const string name;
    const Class super;
    const size_t size;
    void (* ctor)(object, pointer);
    void (* dtor)(object);
};

struct str_Intern_Object{
    pointer data;
    Class class_pointer;
};
```

O problema é que, se a função `add_std_func` for definida fora da DLL (no próprio projeto ou em uma biblioteca estática), o código funciona normalmente; mas, quando está na DLL, o código causa uma falha de segmentação ao acessar o parâmetro `list`. A DLL é adicionada por meio de argumento para o link do compilador (GCC).
Alguém sabe por que isso está acontecendo?

Comment: Um DLL é um biblioteca dinámica (Dynamically Linked Library). Por que você está tentando ligar um DLL estaticamente? O normal é chamar LoadLibrary dentro do programa. LoadLibrary dê o lugar e nome do DLL que deve adicionar. Se não adicionou, o programa não pode achar a função.

Comment: Neste caso, a DLL é apenas uma parte independente do código, mas que deve estar presente, sendo que, apenas `add_std_func` e uma outra função para registro de callback são diretamente chamadas pelo código principal. A ideia é apenas poder atualizar a DLL sem precisar recompilar o restante do projeto.

Comment: Então, você não quer ligação estática. Você está chamando `LoadLibrary` e `GetProcAddress` antes de chamar `add_std_func`?

Comment: A DLL é adicionada ao linker durante a compilação, portanto é carregada quando a aplicação é inicializada (gerando uma mensagem de erro quando não encontrada). O ponto é que a DLL é encontrada e a função `add_std_func` é executada, porém há uma falha de segmentação quando a função tenta acessar o parâmetro, o que não acontece se estiver em uma biblioteca estática.

Comment: Não conheço um jeito de ligar um DLL estáticamente. Você presica ter um 'header' na hora da compilação que declara as funções que o DLL fornece, mas a ligação acontece ao correr com LoadLibrary e GetProcAddress.

Comment: Há um header onde a função `add_std_func` é declarada. A DLL, nesse caso, funciona como uma biblioteca, porém é carregada em tempo de execução e não de compilação, como no caso das bibliotecas estáticas. Nesse caso, não há a necessidade de utilizar `LoadLibrary` e `GetProcAddress` e eu não gostaria de utilizá-las porque pretendo manter o código o mais portável possível.

Comment: Como parece o código onde está acessando `list`?

Comment: Esse código é um pouco extenso e possui dependências, mas vou deixar o link para o projeto no github [aqui](https://github.com/thiagofleal/Interpretador/blob/Atualiza%C3%A7%C3%A3o/Shared/sharedMain.c).

Answer (score 0):

Como você está fazendo em C como está no título e tag da pergunta. [Pergunta que eu respondi leia](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/178823/erro-de-refer%C3%AAncia-na-dll/509759#509759), diferente do C++ funciona assim:

```
/* Replace "dll.h" with the name of your header */
#include "dll.h"
#include <windows.h>

DLLIMPORT void HelloWorldC()
{
    MessageBox(0,"Olá mundo de uma DLL em C!\n","Hi",MB_ICONINFORMATION);
}

DLLIMPORT int AddC(int a, int b)
{
    return a+b;
}

DLLIMPORT int SubC(int a, int b)
{
    return a-b;
}

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL,DWORD fdwReason,LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
    switch(fdwReason)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        {
            break;
        }
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        {
            break;
        }
        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        {
            break;
        }
        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    
    /* Return TRUE on success, FALSE on failure */
    return TRUE;
}
```

Apenas adicionando algumas funções e temos o exemplo da dllmain.c. A semelhança é que tem o include do cabeçalho e a função WINAPI (Olhe o link acima) a diferença que no cabeçalho e nesse arquivo tem que colocar o `dllexport`.

```
#ifndef _DLL_H_
#define _DLL_H_

#if BUILDING_DLL
#define DLLIMPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLLIMPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

DLLIMPORT void HelloWorldC();
DLLIMPORT int AddC(int a, int b);
DLLIMPORT int SubC(int a, int b);

#endif
```

Aqui também se coloca o `dllexport` e pode colocar no: `__declspec tipo nome` ou `tipo __declspec nome`. Ao compilar recebe a dll e a .lib ou .a, leia a pergunta que eu respondi em questão de incluir a lib (se você tem dúvida) e logo em seguida criamos um cabeçalho de métodos:

```
#ifndef C_H
#define C_H

    #define CDLL __declspec(dllimport)

    extern "C"
    {
        CDLL void HelloWorldC();
        CDLL int AddC(int a, int b);
        CDLL int SubC(int a, int b);
    }

#endif
```

Sempre na hora do `dllimport` coloque os items a importar em `extern "C"` pois é importante, se não colocar o compilador vai dar `undefined reference` se usar em C++ ou C. Para saber se seus métodos estão sendo importados use o [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No final compila e

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu fiz apenas de função mas isso vale para esses items de sua pergunta.